# How do I get the rows from my DataFrame based on the number of the top 10 value_counts?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Right now, I have this code block here that does what I want. However, I'm am hard coding the occurrences so that means if i upload another dataset or change the Quarter, 32 might not be the 10th most number of occurrences and I have to manually change it. Is there a way for me to make this not hard coded?

```
df_complaints = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mengchoontan/school-239/master/complaints-2020-02-08_03_28.csv", encoding="latin")
df_complaints.rename(columns={'Date received': 'Quarter', 'Company': 'Bank'}, inplace=True)
df_complaints['Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df_complaints['Quarter'])
df_complaints = df_complaints.sort_values(by = 'Quarter', ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)
df_complaints['Quarter'] = df_complaints['Quarter'].dt.quarter

df_Q1 = df_complaints[df_complaints['Quarter'] == 1]
df_Q1['Bank'].value_counts().head(10)
df_Top10 = df_Q1.groupby('Bank').filter(lambda x : len(x)>32) #Right now I am hardcoding this by first checking what the 10th occurrence is then showing those that appear more than that
df_Top10['ID']=df_Top10.index
df_Top10 = df_Top10[['ID', 'Quarter', 'Bank']]
df_Top10['Bank'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get minimal value to variable `m` and then change condition to `>=`:

```
df_Q1 = df_complaints[df_complaints['Quarter'] == 1]
m = df_Q1['Bank'].value_counts().head(10).min()
print (m)
33
df_Top10 = df_Q1.groupby('Bank').filter(lambda x : len(x)>=m)
```

Or for improve performance:

```
df_Top10 = df_Q1[df_Q1.groupby('Bank')['Bank'].transform('size') >= m]
```

Comment: @Aaron - Because `filter` is slow in pandas, unfortunately. I am not pandas developer, so only guess because `filter` is coded like generally function, so slow, because some edge cases can be used.